# Wimpy duct tape?

Tags: duct-tape

I just bought a roll of "professional" class 1 duct tape and the adhesive on it is extremely wimpy.

I think the last time I bought duct tape was 10 years ago and it had a thick, white adhesive that was extremely sticky--nothing like what I just bought.

Is there some "new normal" for duct tape in which its adhesive is wimpy, or did I get the wrong stuff?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get good stuff with aggressive adhesive go for this tape:

[image]

*(I am just a user of this product and can vouch for its value)*

Comment: I like gorilla tape because it comes off clean, not leaving a sticky mess behind.

Comment: If you use gorilla tape to secure something to the windows of a motor home and then leave it in place for some months you will experience the glue staying on the window. It had to be removed with solvent and a razor blade.

Comment: Here you can see the reason some clear Lexan panels with things mounted on it were Gorilla taped to the inside of the motorhome windows. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-xW09lvta4

Comment: @MichaelKaras that is going to happen with any adhesive, the culprit is UV from the sun.  Taping to Lexan is much worse, and is sure to ruin the Lexan unless the tape is removed quite soon. I got sick of people ruining woodwork and door paint and finally painted the doors in LPU.  Solved.

Answer (score 0):

You didn’t say what you were planning on using it for, duct tape is used for almost anything but ducts these days. Back in the old days we used cloth duct tape. This was fine when you first put it on but when it was heated and cooled over the years the glue would crumble. There is now 2 types of tape I use for ducts although I mostly use caulking where practical. The first type is cheap but won’t come off if properly installed. It is similar to packing tape and if it is approved it will have 181 approved all over it. The second type is very expensive but has more wear resistance and looks nicer. It has a pressure sensitive butyl adhesive with a foil backing. With both types the surface must be clean and you need to massage the tape into the ducts. Do this and it will never come off. If you are just using it for general projects usually the cheaper duct tape has a higher initial stickiness than the more expensive stuff.